# How do I create a timer that runs in the background in Android?

Tags: android

I am making a count up timer
Of course, it should work in the background as well.
I understand that in Android 8 and higher, notifications can be displayed as a foreground service when running in the background.

Is it possible to create a timer that runs in the background with just these tasks?
What else needs to be done?